# Drawing Google Maps polyline directions using flutter_polyline_points - not "snapped" to roads

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart, google-maps-api-3, flutter-dependencies

I am using the `flutter_polyline_points` package to draw a route between multiple points on my `GoogleMap` widget (providing start point, end point, and multiple points in between).

The polylines are being drawn perfectly fine, and everything seems to work, except for the fact that the polylines are not "snapped" to the roads, and seem like just a line between each point. Please see this example:

[image: Exmaple image]

I am getting the points for the polyline like this:

```
PolylineResult result = await polylinePoints.getRouteBetweenCoordinates(
      kGooglePlacesAPIKey,
      PointLatLng(
        startPoint.latitude,
        startPoint.longitude,
      ),
      PointLatLng(
        endPoint.latitude,
        endPoint.longitude,
      ),
      wayPoints: myAddresses.map((currAddress) {
        return PolylineWayPoint(
          location: '${currAddress.latitude},${currAddress.longitude}',
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
```

Does anyone know why it is occurring? Or an alternative to this package that can help me achieve more "snapped" and accurate results?

Thank you

Comment: Hi, I am facing this problem in my current project. Any solution?